# iphone view controller transition using storyboard

Tags: iphone, storyboard, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am making my iPhone app using storyboard.
Initial view controller has a button, and when clicked it, the new view controller should be appeared from right side.
Now when I select Push or Custom in Story board Segues on the button, new view controller never appear.
When I select Modal, the new view controller appears from bottom to top.

Question.
1. Why the new view controller is not appear in Push or Custom mode?
2. How can I show the new view controller from right to the left when the button on the main screen is clicked?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Push segues can only be used if the view controller is contained within a navigation controller.  If you want to use a push-style segue without being embedded in a navigation controller, then you need to define your own custom segue class that performs the segue as a push would, but without actually pushing the VC onto the navigation stack.

The reason Custom segue isn't doing anything for you is probably because you haven't defined an actual custom segue to use.

Take a look at the section on storyboards and segues in [What's new in iOS: iOS 5.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1)